# How to use theme block into custom theme Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a paid Magento template. and it has some features like testimonials blog etc. Also i have a custom theme and i want to use the testimonials feature in custom theme which is another store.
I have copy all the files into my custom theme. and i am trying to display like below code. but nothing showing.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('magentothem/testimonial/sidebar/slider.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: try contacting template devolopers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically `('core/template')` was not related to this module. Here you should use to correct block class name.

```
('testimonial/sidebar')
```